# Why some button displayed strangely in Shiny?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

My second button display strangely sometimes. Anyone encountered the same situation? any solutions?

[image]

The second button is a download function, coding as following:

```
 downloadButton('downloadData', 'Export Keywords'),
```

I'm using the following style:

```
tags$head(
        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "bootstrap.css")
#tags$style(HTML('#run{background-color:orange}'))
),
```

I tried to specify the width and height under css file of the button class. After that, it shows: 
[image]

I think the root of the problem is that the lable for the button is missing at run time. When comparing the html code, I found:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-success 
    shiny-bound-input" id="runButton" type="button">Run Analysis! 
  </button>

   <a id="downloadData" class="btn btn-default shiny-download-link 
     btn-success shiny-bound-output"
     href="downloadData?w=" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible example please

Comment: @PorkChop thanks for the comment. The problem randomly occurs to me. Half of the time, it's working right. So I think it's hard to reproduce it with given code.

Comment: I think the style you're adding to the Run Analysis might be affecting the download button

Comment: thanks @PorkChop, just added in my code fragment that relates to style setting.

Comment: I found the main reason is that I have a shiny::validate() function under downloadHandler() function. This causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved after I remove following function from downloadHandler()

> shiny::validate()